# Why isn't my addOnSuccesListener working?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get any user that has "like" or "dislike" as string value besides myself, but my code is simply jumping of to the end of the function without executing the code inside. What do I have to change? I tried in another project to test and it worked fine, I just did a copy and paste with the function and now it isn't working.

Sorry for my poor english, I'm brazillian.

```
private void getMyIdEqualLike() {
        Query query = usersReferenceDb.document(userCardViewID).collection("connections").whereEqualTo(myUId, "like");
        query.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                uConnectID = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments().toString();
            }
        });
    }
```

The getDocuments() function it's supposed to return a list with a documentSnapshot of my user if it's equal to "like" and if it isn't then returns "[]" as empty list, but I'm getting null from uConnectID variable, so I debugged it step by step and I saw that it stops at "query.get().addOnSuccessListener..." and jump right to the end of it's function.

Comment: You can never step into the `onSuccess` as it's triggered asynchronously. You'll have to set a breakpoint in there, and see if it hits. See my answer here: https://twitter.com/puf/status/1118878354307014656 You might want to also add an `addOnFailureListener(...)` to see if it shows a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `addOnCompleteListener` and check if the `query.get()` is completing successfully or not.

Your code has `onSuccessListener` which will only be triggered if the call was successful.